# Sorting a two dimensional array in python

Tags: python

```
entropies_with_samples = []
for i in range(0,2948):
    entr = entropy(predictProbas[i])
    mixed = [proba_X_train[i],entr]
    entropies_with_samples.append(mixed)

a = np.array(entropies_with_samples)
a.flatten("F")
print(list(chain.from_iterable(entropies_with_samples)))
selection = (sorted(mixed, key=itemgetter(2),reverse= True))
print(selection)
```

example:

```
input = [([0.2,0.10]),0.69, ([0.3,0.67]),0.70, ([0.5,0.68]),0.70, ([0.3,0.67]),0.65]
```

I'm trying to sort such an array at the third position.

```
output = [([0.3,0.67]),0.70,  ([0.5,0.68]),0.70, ([0.2,0.10]),0.69, ([0.3,0.67]),0.65 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step could be to create a nested list, adding every `2` elements to a new sublist:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

i = [([0.2,0.10]),0.69, ([0.3,0.67]),0.70, ([0.5,0.68]),0.70, ([0.3,0.67]),0.65]

l = [i[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(i),2)]
# [[[0.2, 0.1], 0.69], [[0.3, 0.67], 0.7], [[0.5, 0.68], 0.7], [[0.3, 0.67], 0.65]]
```

And then sort the nested list by the second element in each sublist with `operator.itemgetter`, and use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the result:

```
list(chain(*sorted(l, key = itemgetter(1), reverse=True)))

[[0.3, 0.67], 0.7, [0.5, 0.68], 0.7, [0.2, 0.1], 0.69, [0.3, 0.67], 0.65]
```

Comment: @anna did this help? Remeber to accept the answer it it did, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with zip and sorting with a lambda sorting key:

First, put your "third position" in a tuple with the first and second number, using zip:

```
output = list(zip(output[::2], output[1::2]))
#[([0.3, 0.67], 0.7), ([0.5, 0.68], 0.7), ([0.2, 0.1], 0.69), ([0.3, 0.67], 0.65)]
```

And then sort, using your third number (in the tuple it's on position 2) as the sorting key:

```
output.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
#[([0.3, 0.67], 0.65), ([0.2, 0.1], 0.69), ([0.3, 0.67], 0.7), ([0.5, 0.68], 0.7)]
```